# How to clear form fields after a submit in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I've this:

```py
def profile(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            new_message = Message(author = request.user)
            form = MessagesForm(request.POST, instance = new_message)
        else:
            form = MessagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        to_user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        form = MessagesForm(initial = {'user': to_user.pk})

    return render(request, "profile.html", {
        'username': username,
        'form': form,
        'messages': messages,
    })
```

This form submit a message and return the same page. My problem is that after the submit I see again my field filled with my information. How to clear it after the submit?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It's standard to redirect after form submission to prevent duplicates.

Just return a redirect to your form on success.

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    return http.HttpResponseRedirect('')
```

Comment: Whai if I can't do redirect? - Form as site plugin in Django-CMS. Is there any different way?

Comment: @robos85, not sure what you mean here. If you don't do it through django, then do it on the client side.

Comment: I know this is old.  But when I try using `HttpResponseRedirect('')`, I get a blank white page after submission.  The form is successfully submitted though.  I'm on Django 1.11

Comment: @Valachio are you accidentally returning `HttpResponse('')` (a blank page?) Also, make sure you plug in the URL you want to redirect to. It could be that your POST handling view is strictly a post handler, and redirecting to itself shows nothing. Returning `HttpResponseRedirect('')` redirects you to the same page.

Comment: I get the same behaviour as @Valachio when returning `HttpResponseRedirect('')` with Django 2.2.2. The view is not just a POST handler.

Comment: See @Karthikkumar's answer to avoid sending a redirect.

Answer (score 52):

After saving form instead of showing post dict assign the empty form

```
form = EmployeeForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        pDict = request.POST.copy() 
        form = EmployeeForm(pDict) #if not valid shows error with previous post values in corresponding field
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = EmployeeForm() # show empty form no need to give HttpResponseRedirect()
```

Comment: This should be the answer for the question

Comment: Actually pressing F5 or reloading the page will send the previously submitted data, not a blank form. So redirecting to another url is the best way out.

Comment: redirect the page wont be a good option most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

after save() you can return 'form' key with MessagesForm(request.GET) value.

```py
return render(request, "profile.html", {
        'username': username,
        'form': MessagesForm(request.GET),
        'messages': messages,
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can initialize the same empty form after you have saved datas:

```
if request.method == "POST":
    rf = RegistrationForm(request.POST)
    if rf.is_valid():
        print 'Saving datas..'
        #logic to save datas
        rf = PreRegistrationForm()
        return render_to_response('registration/confirmation_required.html', {'settings': settings}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: Actually pressing F5 or reloading the page will send the previously submitted data, not a blank form. So redirecting to another url is the best way out.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `HttpResponseRedirect('/')` instead of `HttpResponseRedirect('')` in @Karthikkumar's answer, especially if your home view is an empty path, for instance you have in your urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns = [path('',views.home_view),]
```

I had similar issues as those discussed above where `HttpResponseRedirect('')` directed me to a blank page.  Let me know if adding the slash works for you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Sometimes you can use this idea take attrs={ "autocomplete":"off"} for each inputs.
```

Comment: Don't just add an answer, try explaining your answer so it will make others understand your solution

Answer (score 0):

You can redirect back to the initial post

```
post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
return HttpResponseRedirect(post_url)
```

please note that 'post' is an instance of the model created

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you have already defined a logic for GET methods. In the case that you have, all you can do is simply add return **request.META['HTTP_REFERER']** at the end.

See what I mean:

```
def profile(request, username):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            new_message = Message(author = request.user)
            form = MessagesForm(request.POST, instance = new_message)
        else:
            form = MessagesForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        to_user = User.objects.get(username = username)
        form = MessagesForm(initial = {'user': to_user.pk})
    
    return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META['HTTP_REFERER'])
```

This should work, I just tested it.

Answer (score 0):

**Maybe I am late but for Django 4.x developers can use: **

```
from .forms import TodoForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def mytodos(request):
   form = TodoForm()
   if request.method =='POST':
      form=TodoForm(request.POST)
      if form.is_valid:
         form.save()
         messages.success(request,'Task saved successfully')
         return HttpResponseRedirect('/todo/')
   mycontext={'form':form}
   return render(request, 'todo/todo.html',mycontext)
```

in my urls.py: , i have set `path('todo/',views.mytodo, name='todolist')`
As you can see, after saving form, mycode will redirect to /todo/ which is automatically refreshed after every submit and a fresh form comes again everytime. If you are a good django dev, you will understand what I did. Make sure to reply if you have any queries .Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

When we **reload the page** `(F5 or ctrl+shift+R)`, it submits the previously sent data. so instead of refreshing, we will **directly hit the url** using `return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/')`

This way it will show the page with empty form (now even if you refresh it will only show data, won't submit it previous data again)

```
from django.shortcuts import render, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views import View
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm

class PostListView(View):    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        posts = Post.objects.filter(author=request.user).order_by('-created_on')
        form = PostForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_post = form.save(commit=False)
            new_post.author = request.user 
            new_post.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/posts/')

        context = {
            'post_list': posts,
            'form': form
        }

        return render(request, 'social/post_list.html', context)
```