# django auth framework prepopulating form incorrectly, giving random data to fields upon load

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I am trying to create a portable auth system that can be plugged in apps, and each different app I reimplement it in has the same issues.

1-Sometimes the user that recently logged in gets their sn in the email address field when a new user tries to register, as below

2- Sometimes a new user registers and logs out but the form will put the old user's email address and password in the appropriate fields, when of course I want the form to be blank if the user has logged out

3- always the last password used is filled in upon reload

I just want the form to completely clear itself when reloaded[image]

[How to clear form fields after a submit in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773408/how-to-clear-form-fields-after-a-submit-in-django)

I have tried all 3 solutions from a similar question, I reinstantiated the from after saving the valid one, made a copy of request.POST and used that instead, and I was already redirecting to begin with. Here is my form

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserForm(forms.ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'password')
```

in views.py

```
def register(request):
    context = RequestContext(request)
    registered = False

    user_form = UserForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pDict = request.POST.copy()
        form = UserForm(pDict)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = form.save()
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()
            user_form = UserForm()
            registered = True
            username = pDict['username']
            password = pDict['password']
            user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
            login(request, user)

            #locals isn't working? won't print user
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/url/')
        else:
            print user_form.errors

    template_name = 'accounts/register.html'
    user_form = UserForm()
    response = TemplateResponse(request, 'accounts/register.html', locals())

    return response
```

thank you

Comment: Copying `request.POST` is just totally useless, and as long as you redirect after a successful post (which is the case here), there's no need to reinstanciate the form thrice or more. IOW : your problem is elsewhere.  There are also quite a few other useless stuff in your code, like creating a unused `RequestContext` and an unused `template_name` variable, erasing the form's errors if the validation fails, and relying on `locals()` for the context (it's safer, more robust and more readable to populate your context explicitely).   Also you didn't post your template code...

Comment: `<form id="user_form" method="post" action="/accounts/register/"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ user_form.as_p }}
               <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" />`

        `{% endif %}
    <br /><br />
    <a href="/accounts/login/">Already have an account?</a>
    <br /><br />
    <a href="/calendar/">Return home</a>`

`{% endblock %}`

Comment: it appears to be normal browser behavior, and I wonder if it will even matter since users all use different devices?

Comment: except for the hard-coded urls all over the place (do yourself a favour and learn to use the `{% url %}` template tag and it's sibling function the `urlresolvers.reverse()` function), your form seems ok, so yes I think it's your browser's "form autocompletion" feature that gets in the way ;)

Comment: is that out of my control mr. desthuilliers or can I deactivate that within django? as in tell my app not to talk to the autocomplete?

Comment: I don't think there's any way you can hope your server code to take control over such features of the user-agent - hopefully (that would be kind of insecure if any website could take control of your browser, wouldn't it ?). And you shouldn't care anyway - people having this as an active feature of their browser will mostly expect such a behaviour on just any form. All you can do would be to try and deactivate this feature on your own browser (if only to validate the hypothesis that it's the browser's autocomplete feature kicking in).

Comment: I did deactivate google's form autocomplete, and it turns out the issue is in my app. Although I don't expect users' phones/laptops to get stolen, at this point I'm really curious- I even prepopulated the form with a blank user and same issue `blank = {'username': '', 'password': '', 'email': ''}` `user_form = UserForm(initial=blank)`

Comment: Then the problem is somewhere else in your code, but since my crystal ball is out for repair I'm afraid I can't help more.