# Django: return response and return reverse together

Tags: python, django, forms, url

After submitting a form, I would like two things to happen:

- Form is reset (reload the form empty) /or redirected
- Return a file as attachment

Now, I get the dialogue to download file, but form does not reset/re-load empty /nor redirected. I can amend `get_success_url` but then I do not get the download dialogue

I have tried figure out how to do it, but need to help/hints with how I should think to be able to solve it.

What is a solution to get a download dialogue at the same time the form is resetting after successfully accepting the data?

Simplified code below:

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('product/csv/', ProductFormView.get_csv, name='product-csv'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
class ProductFormView(FormView):
    form_class = ProductForm
    model = Product

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('product-csv')

    def get_csv(request):
        csv = FileDB.objects.latest('id').csvfile
        response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/CSV')
        response.write(csv.ToString())
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename='f" {filename} + .csv"
        return response
```

Comment: Did you check this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5773408/how-to-clear-form-fields-after-a-submit-in-django

Comment: Hi, problem is not to reset the form, I can do that, problem is to trigger a file download AND reset form (in the same routine). Visually, after you click OK on your form, it ask you if you want to save the csv file, of course, the form needs to be reset also. Problem I find is that I need to choose either or and I need to click twice to acheive both tasks. For many I can understand my question is very simple and trivial, and maybe even too simple to bother answer, would appreciate a lot to help in the right direction despite this.,I got stuck  many thanks.